# Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan(x)}\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider

$$ I(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan(t) \, dt - \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan(t) \, dt.$$

Now upon differentiating, we get:

\begin{align*}
I'(x)
&= (1) \cdot \frac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan(x) + \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \cdot \frac{1/x}{1+(1/x)^4}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \\
&= \frac{x}{1+x^4} \cdot \left(\arctan(x) + \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)
\end{align*}

Using the identity $\arctan(x) + \arctan(\frac{1}{x}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and subsequently integrating reveals,

$$ I(x) = \frac{\pi}{4}\cdot \arctan(x^2)$$

Now if I were to replace $x=\infty$, $\frac{1}{x}=0$ and

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan(t) \, dt = \int_{0}^{0} \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan(t) \, dt = 0, $$

which results in:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan(x) \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\pi}{(2\cdot2)} = \bbox[color:navy; border:1px dotted navy; padding:8px;]{ \frac{\pi^2}{8} } $$

**However,** the actual value is almost $\frac{\pi^2}{16}$. Where is my mistake?

Also, I am very new to this topic and don’t know if this method is mathematically valid. Please rectify any mistakes. :)

Also, has this technique been used before?

Comment: It might clarify things to use different letters for the limits of integration and the variable in the integrand. For example, instead of $\int_{0}^{x}{\dfrac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan(x)} dx$, start with $\int_{0}^{t}{\dfrac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan(x)} dx$.

Comment: Okay! I'm not sure enough to make this an answer, but you'll probably want to take more time on the "and subsequently integrating" part. You'll need a constant of integration such that if $x=1$ then the quantity in the first display equals $0$.

For that matter, it might further clarify things to give that display a new name, like $F(x)$. That way, it's easier to write down a succinct claim like $F(1)=0$.

Comment: You can write $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\arctan x}{1+x^{4}}dx = \frac{1}{2}\Im\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{ }\frac{x\operatorname{Log}\left(1+ix\right)}{1+x^{4}}dx$ where $\operatorname{Log}$ takes on the principal branch and integrate over [this path](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d2e5ax3d1v). It would be reallyyyyyy long compared to the other simpler answers you've received, but I'd totally be glad to write an answer if you're willing to read it all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is true is that

$$I(x) - I(0) = \frac{\pi}{4}\arctan(x^2). $$

(Here, $I(x)$ is as in OP, *a priori* defined on $(0, \infty)$ and then extended to $[0, \infty]$ via limit.) You implicitly assumed $I(0) = 0$, but we actually have $I(0) = -I(\infty)$. Rectifying this and letting $x\to\infty$ gives

$$ 2I(\infty) = \frac{\pi^2}{8} , $$

leading to the correct answer $I(\infty)=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$.

Comment: Could you explain how $I(0)+I(\infty)=0$? I'm very new to this :)

Comment: Also I would like to know if anyone derived this integral value in this manner before

Comment: @ManishK, Writing $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan(t) \, dt$, our $I(x)$ is of the form $$I(x)=F(x)-F(1/x). $$ Then $$I(0)=F(0)-F(\infty)\qquad\text{and}\qquad I(\infty)=F(\infty)-F(0), $$ So $I(0) = -I(\infty)$.

Comment: Wonderful thank you

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

One common way to evaluate the integral is the substitution $\arctan x = v$, $x=\tan v$, $dx/dv = 1+\tan^2 v$
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan x dx
= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan v}{1+\tan^4 v} v(1+\tan^2 v) dv
$$
$$
= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin v\cos v}{\cos^4 v+\sin^4 v}v dv
= 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin (2v)}{3+\cos(4 v)}v dv
$$
$$
= \frac12 \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin v}{3+\cos(2 v)}v dv
= \frac14 \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin v}{1+\cos^2 v}v dv
$$
Partial integration yields
$$
= \frac14 (-\arctan \cos v) v\mid_0^{\pi}+\frac14 \int_0^{\pi} \arctan \cos v dv
= \frac14 (-\pi \arctan (-1)+0\arctan 1) +\frac14 \int_0^{\pi} \arctan \cos v dv
$$
$$
= \frac{\pi^2}{16} +\frac14 \int_0^{\pi} \arctan \cos v dv
$$
where the latter intgral is zero because $\cos v$ is appears symmetrically with opposite signs in $[0,\pi/2]$ and $[\pi/2,\pi]$.

Comment: Ohhh so this is the simplest evaluation of the question... Very nice work :)

Answer (score 2):

$$
I(x) \equiv \int_0^x \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan x dt-\int_0^{1/x}\frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan t dt.
$$
After differentiation under the integral sign
$$
I'(x) 
= 
1\times \frac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan x -\frac{-1}{x^2} \frac{1/x}{1+1/x^4}\arctan \frac{1}{x}
= 
\frac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan x +\frac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan \frac{1}{x} 
$$
using $\arctan x +\arctan \frac{1}{x}=\pi/2$ yields
$$
I'(x)
= 
\frac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan x +\frac{x}{1+x^4}(\pi/2-\arctan x)
= 
\frac{x}{1+x^4}\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$
From the definition we know
$$
I(1) = \int_0^1 \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan t dt
-\int_0^1 \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan t dt=0 ;
$$
$$
I(0) = -\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan t dt;
$$
$$
I(\infty) = \int_0^\infty \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan t dt;
$$
Since we are interested at $I(\infty)$ and $I(1)=0$ it suffices to integrate $I'(x)$ starting at $x=1$:
$$
I(\infty)
=\int_1^\infty I'(x) dx
=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_1^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^4}dx
$$
With the substiution $x^2=u$, $du=2xdx$
$$
I(\infty)
=\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{2}\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{1+u^2}du
=\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{2} \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi^2}{16}.
$$

Comment: Wonderful :) Was this method ever discovered before? Because I could find no reference to the solution of the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan(x)}\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$ and had to derive this method independently :)

Comment: The technique to split arctan-integrals from $0$ to $\infty$ at $1$ and to substitute $t=1/x$ in one of the two parts is used for example in https://dx.doi.org/10.1017/mag.2022.75 .

Comment: Thanks a lot for bringing this to my notice :)

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan(x)}\,dx\overset{x\to\frac1x}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan(\frac1x)}\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^4}(\frac\pi2-\arctan(x))}\,dx=-I+\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$
and hence
$$ I=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$$

Comment: I think the substitution would also change the limits of integration and not result in the correct value

Comment: Yes, you are right.