# Generalization of a family of integrals $\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^{2n+2}}\arctan(x)dx=\dfrac{\pi}{4}\int_0^\infty{\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^{2n+2}} }dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I observed that: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^{2n+2}}\arctan(x) dx=\dfrac{\pi}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^{2n+2}} }dx=\dfrac{\pi^2}{4\cdot\left(2n+2\right)}$$

The result is a generalization of my previous post:[Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan(x)}\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4802836), in which one of the integrals belonging to this family was evaluated.

Let, $n=0.5$:

This gives us, according to the generalization:$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^3}\arctan(x)}dx=\dfrac{\pi}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^3} dx=\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Therefore:$$\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^3}\arctan(x)}dx$$

Similarly, $$\dfrac{\pi^2}{20}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{x\sqrt{x}}{1+x^5}\arctan(x)}dx$$

$$\dfrac{\pi^2}{28}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{x^2\sqrt{x}}{1+x^7}\arctan(x)}dx$$And so on...

The values of the RHS evaluated numerically seem to equal the LHS values.

My question is if this identity has been observed before and if it could also be extended to complex values of $n$.

Comment: Some of your definite integrals are missing limits.

Comment: "Let, $x=0.5$" should be "Let $n=0.5$". Shouldn't also "extended to complex values of $x$" be "extended to complex values of $n$"? if not, what does it mean?
.

Comment: $\beta$ function's supremacy!

Comment: Shouldn't  "extended to complex values of $x$
" be "extended to complex values of $n$
"? if not, what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prove the identity for all $n \in \mathbb{C}$, so instead of $n$ I use $z = \sigma + it$ I divide the proof in three steps :

**Step 1**

I show that the integral is well defined for $\sigma > 0$ (it should work also for $\sigma > -1$ but for simplicity I assume $\sigma > 0$)

For (say) $x > 2$  I have

$|\frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}}{\arctan(x)}| \leq \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{|x|^\sigma}{|x|^{2\sigma+2}-1} \leq \pi\frac{1}{|x|^{2+\sigma}}$ which is integrable on $(2,\infty)$

while the function is continuos in $[0,2]$ So it's absolutely integrable in $(0,\infty)$

observe that in order for $x^{2+2z} = -1$ for some $x > 0$ one would need $\Re(2+2z) = 0$ which is $\sigma = -1$

**Step 2**

I show the first Identity

the change of variable $y = 1/x$ yields

$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}}\arctan(x)dx} = \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{y^{-z}}{1+y^{-2z-2}}\frac{1}{y^2}\arctan(1/y)dy} = \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{y^{z}}{y^{2z+2} + 1}\arctan(1/y)dy}$

Therefore

$2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}}\arctan(x)dx} =\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}}\arctan(x)dx} + \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}}\arctan(1/x)dx} = \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}}(\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x))dx} = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}}dx}$

divide by $2$ to find

$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}}\arctan(x)dx} = \frac{\pi}{4}{ \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}}dx} }$

**Step 3**

Using once again $y = 1/x$ I find

$\int_{1}^{\infty}{ \frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}} dx} = \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}}dx} $

so that

$\frac{\pi}{4}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{ \frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}} dx }} = \frac{\pi}{2}{\int_{0}^1{ \frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}} dx }}$

and now since the integration interval is compact and for any $0 < x < 1$ the function $z \mapsto \frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}}$ is holomorphic one can easily show that the function

$I(z) := {\int_{0}^{1}{ \frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}} dx }}$ is an holomorphic function

**Step 4**

now suppose $z = t > 0$, then I use $y = x^{t+1}$ to find

$I(t) = \frac{1}{t+1}{\int_{0}^{1}{ \frac{1}{1+y^2} dy }} = \frac{1}{t+1}\frac{\pi}{4}$

**Final step**

Let now $h(z) := \frac{\pi}{4}\frac{1}{z+1}$, it is an holomorphic function and I have showed that
$I(z) = h(z)$ forall $z > 0$, so by the [Identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) $I(z) = h(z)$

therefore

$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z}} \arctan(x)dx} = \frac{\pi}{2}I(z) = \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{1}{z+1} = \frac{\pi^2}{4\cdot(2z+2)}$

this holds for all $\Re(z) > -1$

Comment: Very nice, I'm not sure I have the mathematical knowledge to understand this though :) 

Answer (score 3):

The following is a simplified version of [@Paul's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4803017) (+1).

The three functions
$$\begin{align}f(z)&:=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}}\arctan x\,dx,\\g(x)&:=\frac\pi4\int_0^\infty\frac{x^z}{1+x^{2z+2}}\,dx,\\h(z)&:=\frac{\pi^2}{8(z+1)},
\end{align}$$
are holomorphic on the open half plane $D:=\{z\in\Bbb C\mid\Re(z)>-1\}$ and, as you already observed, coincide on $(-1,+\infty),$ the proof being exactly the same as in the [case $z=1$ of your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4802855).

Therefore, by the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), they coincide on $D.$

Comment: . I should research all the relevant topics mentioned here to fully understand it. Thank you regardless. Just a follow up question, has this family of integrals been observed elsewhere before?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, but this is highly probable, as an exercise in some textbook(s).