# Evaluating integrals with complex limits

Tags: calculus, integration

Following up [Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan(x)}\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4802836) In the mentioned question, OP considered the function:$$ I(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan(t) \ dt - \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan(t) \ dt.$$ The resulting(corrected) value of $I(x)$ was :$$I(x)=\dfrac{\pi}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{x}{1+x^4}} dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{x\arctan(x)}{1+x^4}} dx$$ If I were to replace $x=i$, then the resulting answer would be $$ I(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan(t) \ dt - \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan(t) \ dt.$$ $$ I(x) = \int_{0}^{i} \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan(t) \ dt + \int_{-i}^{0} \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan(t) \ dt.$$ Which is essentially:$$\int_{-i}^{i} \frac{t}{1+t^4}\arctan(t) \ dt$$ And the resulting $I(x)$ value is(Considering $\arctan(i)+\arctan(1/i)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$):$$\dfrac{\pi}{4}\int_{0}^{i}{\dfrac{x}{1+x^4}} dx$$ So,$$\int_{-i}^{i} \frac{x}{1+x^4}\arctan(x) \ dx=\dfrac{\pi}{4}\int_{0}^{i}{\dfrac{x}{1+x^4}} dx$$ However I feel that this might be entirely wrong and I am making a lot of mistakes. Please rectify my mistakes? Is it wrong to consider $\infty-\infty=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$? Or is there any other underlying issue I failed to see?

Answer (score 1):

We know the antiderivative in terms of logarithms and polylogarithms (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5B%28t*ArcTan%5Bt%5D%29%2F%281+%2B+t%5E4%29%2Ct%5D)).

Using the bounds and just computing, after a few simplifications,
$$\int_{-i}^{+i} \frac{t}{1+t^4}\,\,\arctan(t) \ dt=i\frac{\pi}{32}  \log \left(156808-110880 \sqrt{2}\right)+$$
$$\frac 14  \left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac
   {1}{2} \left(1+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\right)-$$
$$\frac 14  \left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac
   {1}{2}
   \left(1-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac
   {1}{2}
   \left(1+\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\right)$$ Numerically, this is
$$-0.69222919651217017941796294493499349510310898215009 \,i$$ for which inverse symbolic calculators do not propose anything.